# reading from a non constant char* array

Tags: c

I compiled the following code using gcc TDM 64bit

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "Tom 28";
    char name[10];
    int age, ret;

    printf("str= %s\n", str);
    ret = sscanf(str, "%s %d", name, &age);
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);

    str[4] = '5';

    printf("str= %s\n", str);
    ret = sscanf(str, "%s %d", name, &age);
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);

    exit( 0 );
}
```

why there is no output after changing the str[12]. Here is the output

```
str= Tom 28
Name: Tom
Age: 28
```

only blank line. My goal is reading from a dynamically allocated char array

```
long long len = 10;
char* s = malloc( sizeof(*s) * len );
```

Comment: In `str[12] = '5'`, `str`  is a string literal and string literals can not be modified (and even if it was writable you are accessing outside of the bounds of the array and this is UB), does it compile?

Comment: Changing memory you did not allocate is Undefined Behavior.  (You didn't allocate the space for "Tom 28".)

Comment: `str[12]` does not exist (you have `str[0] == 'T'`, ... `str[6] == '\0'` and that's it). Even if it existed it would be **read-only**.

Comment: I had a typo I corrected it. str[4] = '5';

Comment: Actually, I want to read from a dynamically allocated char array:
long long len = 10;
char* s = malloc( sizeof(*s) * len );

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a pointer to a `char` (or array of `char`s in this case), and at the first line of `main` you assign it the value "Tom 28", which makes it *point* to the string "Tom 28" which is at some unknown location in memory.

When you do `str[12] = '5'`, you write to an arbitrary memory location, which is Undefined Behaviour. Whatever happens after that line of code can be anything, and it doesn't make sense to try to explain it. Your program could have crashed, you could have overwritten an arbitrary variable, causing the behavior of the application to change. It depends on many things such as compiler, memory layout, cpu architecture, operating system, and so on.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but the line `str[12] = '5'` is just wrong and removing it should solve the problem.

Comment: So how I can read from a dynamically allocated array. At the end of the question I wrote it.long long len = 10;
char* s = malloc( sizeof(*s) * len );

Comment: @MohammadNakhaee, you can read from your dynamically allocated array (after checking it is not `NULL`) using `s[0]` or `*s`, just like you would read from any other array. Please ask only one question at the same time in the future. (You may want to take the [tour] if you haven't done so, to learn how Stack Overflow works.)